# macOS Ventura has two copies of Postgres in Login Items

Tags: homebrew, ventura, login-items, postgresql

Just notice my Mac (running macOS Ventura 13.1) has two copies of **postgres** listed as Login Items in `System Settings > General > Login Items`.  Clicking on the (i) button for EITHER one opens a Finder window highlighting the same file:

`Macintosh HD/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.6/bin/postgres`

Note: there is a symlink at `Macintosh HD/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgres` that points to the 14.6 directory (above).  Perhaps one of these Login Items is pointing at the symlink and the other at the executable. But effectively they're both pointing at the same thing.

Why is this duplicated? Safe to deselect (or somehow remove) one of them?

[image]

Update:

I have found two **launchd** PostgreSQL plist files in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` which I believe to be the culprit:

```
homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14.plist
```

They are basically identical except one points to `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres` while the other points to `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/bin/postgres`

So, I guess my question now is...which one to delete?

As mentioned above `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql` is a symlink to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14`

So...which launchd plist to delete?!?

Comment: Did you upgrade or reinstall postgres recently?  An installer may not check properly for existing items in Startup, so it just adds another. Check Activity monitor to see if you are running multiple instances of the server

Comment: Only one process running `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres`

Comment: Then it’s just a duplicate startup item.  For grins and giggles, if you try manually starting the server (via command line), it will likely error out and tell you a server/process instance is already running. Just delete one of the Start Up items and you’ll be fine.  Post your results as an answer and ping me with a reply to this comment and I’ll upvote.

Comment: I've upgraded from macOS 12 to 13.1, and I am now seeing the same problem: I have two login items for postgres as described above. They appear to pertain to the same (14.6) binary, and I don't seem to be able to delete either one. I have postgres installed via homebrew.

I also get a barrage of "Background Items Added: 'postgres' is an item that can run in the background". Notifications. One for each entry spaced about 10s apart. The only way I can fix this seems to be to turn off the login items.

Comment: Found 2 launchd plists (see update to main question above)